# Who to follow on Twitter if you are interested in Ubuntu?

Tags: community, twitter

I'd like to know whom I should follow on Twitter, to get my daily dose of Ubuntu news, tips, and random bits.

Which members from the Ubuntu community are active on Twitter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are people related to Ubuntu, in some capacity or other. Most of them are developers, and UI designers. Some are fansites. I will keep adding more as I find them.

Ubuntu Evangelist, and owner of Canonical: [Mark Shuttleworth](http://twitter.com/#!/sabdfl).

Unity’s Technical Lead and Canonical DX Team Member: [Neil Patel](http://twitter.com/#!/njpatel).

Fansite: [OMG Ubuntu](http://twitter.com/omgubuntu).

Fansite: [Ubuntu Gamer](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntugamer).

Blog and Fansite: [Planet Ubuntu](http://twitter.com/#!/planetubuntu).

[Linux](https://twitter.com/#!/Linux).

Canonical Design Team Lead: [Ivanka Majic](http://twitter.com/#!/ivanka)

Ubuntu Engineering Director: [Rick Spencer](http://twitter.com/#!/rickspencer3)

UX & visual designer for Ubuntu: [Mateusz Tomaszewski](http://twitter.com/#!/mattomaszewski)

Open Source Consultant, Developer: [Richard Johnson](http://twitter.com/#!/nixternal)

Ubuntu Community Manager: [Jono Bacon](http://twitter.com/#!/jonobacon)

Official Twitter Channel of The Ubuntu Cloud: [UbuntuOne](http://twitter.com/#!/UbuntuOne)

The Canonical Design Team: [Ubuntu Designers](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntudesigners)

Project Manager at Ubuntu: [Iain Farell](https://twitter.com/#!/iainfarrell)

Comment: Marks account is inactive since 10th Oct .

Comment: @Alaukik its there, more out of respect ;) If OP wants some doses, he should follow Mark's blog :)

Answer (score 15):

[Jorge Castro](http://twitter.com/#!/castrojo) ([website](http://about.me/jorge.castro))

[Ask Ubuntu](http://twitter.com/#!/search/stackubuntu) ([website](https://askubuntu.com/)) :D

[Wepupd8](http://twitter.com/#!/webupd8) ([website](http://www.webupd8.org/))

[Ubuntuka](http://twitter.com/#!/Ubuntuka) ([website](http://www.ubuntuka.com/))

[Ubuntu podcast](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntupodcast) ([website](http://ubuntupodcast.net/))

[Ubuntu podcast UK](http://twitter.com/#!/uupc) ([website](http://podcast.ubuntu-uk.org/))

[Ubuntujames](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntujames) ([Website](http://2buntu.com/))

Ubuntu chick [Nixie pixel](http://twitter.com/#!/search/nixiepixe) ([website](http://www.nixiepixel.com/))

[Full circle magazine](https://twitter.com/#!/fullcirclemag)  ([website](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/)).

[Ubuntu Manual](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntumanual) ([website](http://ubuntumanual.org/))

Dutch:
[Ubuntu NL](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntunl) ([website](http://www.ubuntu-nl.org/))

Comment: I am already following him :)

Comment: who doesn't? >:-D

Answer (score 13):

A few that haven't been mentioned from those I'm following:

- [Matthew Paul Thomas](http://twitter.com/#!/mpt) (mpt) is heavily involved in design work at Canonical
- [Aaron Bockover](http://twitter.com/#!/abock) founded and continues to develop Banshee
- [Michael Larabel](http://twitter.com/#!/michaellarabel) runs Phoronix (popular hardware and benchmarking website)
- [Marco Ceppi](http://twitter.com/#!/marcoceppi) is a moderator on this very site
- [Asa Doltzer](http://twitter.com/#!/asadotzler) works at Mozilla and posts lots of Firefox stuff
- The [Ubuntu Developers](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntudev) account has all sorts of goodness
- The [Ubuntu UK Podcast](http://twitter.com/#!/uupc)

Comment: I recommend the Ubuntu UK Podcast, an excellent & enthusiastic bunch of people.

Comment: I wish I could accept all of these answers :)

Answer (score 5):

- [Ubuntu Vibes](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntuvibes) has interesting information too, game oriented.
- [Ubuntu Status](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntustatus) has news about security updates.
- [Ubuntu One](http://twitter.com/#!/UbuntuOne) posts status information about Ubuntus cloud service.

Answer (score 5):

Our blog, [2buntu](https://twitter.com/#!/2buntu/) (link to the blog [here](http://2buntu.com)), recently launched a twitter feed as well. We try to regularly post tips etc, and our blog posts are auto-tweeted.

Personally I also follow

- [techiebuzzer](http://twitter.com/techiebuzzer)
- [ubuntujames](http://twitter.com/ubuntujames)

Answer (score 4):

New to twitter, a must follow : )

- [**Unity**](https://twitter.com/#!/ubuntuunity)

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend following the Ubuntu group in identi.ca:

http://identi.ca/group/ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

[UbuntuGeek](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntugeek)([Website](http://www.ubuntugeek.com))

Answer (score 1):

[ubuntusecurity](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntusecurity) and [ubuntudesigners](http://twitter.com/#!/ubuntudesigners)